# How to display multiple models in one tab in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I made the item and quiz apps with the startapp command.

I added the apps to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and registered them on the admin page.

`admin.site.register(Item)`

`admin.site.register(Quiz)`

In the admin page, Item tab and Quiz tab exist separately, and models can be modified in each tab.

I want to combine these two tabs into a tab called 'foo'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You've to register all models in one **admin.py** file

Comment: Are they related to each other ?

Comment: @Gaëtan GR
The two apps are separate apps that are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari
I tried that method, but it didn't solve this problem. Both item and quiz were registered in admin.py in the item folder, but each tab was shown separately in the admin page

Comment: I think that you can add in the model class Meta `app_label=app name`